# Unmanaged c++ testing framework integration with Visual Studio 2008 (GUI Test runner)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cppunit, googletest

One thing I like about Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework is that all the unit testing is done from withing the IDE, from class definition to running the test having a graphical green/red bar giving test results.

I'm using both CppUnit and Google Test to test my applications. I quite succeeded integrating both in Visual Studio IDE, given a text output.

I'm wondering if anybody build a Visual Studio Addin allowing to both run the test from within DevStudio and having a graphical test runner to give the feedback?

Thanks,

Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found an interesting way to do what I was looking for.

I created a project of the kind "VisualStudioPackage" (VsPackage) that is used to add custom functionality to the development environment.

In that project, I wrapped the CppUnit test runner and add a custom test listener that is used to refresh the stats in a Window (provided in by the VsPackage) in DevStudio.

I also added a custom command to start unit testing my project.

Comment: Sounds very good, do you have it available for other to use? Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate it very much! My address in gmail is just my name.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find an integration for either project.  What some people are doing at my company is to write their tests in c++/cli that can be run with the mstest.  It is a little gross, but it is *a* solution.